# Use eigenface on Android (faint)

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

How could I use eigenface on my android application to do some facial recognition? I've found some project such as faint http://faint.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId837572
But have no idea how to use it in my own application.
Can anyone help me? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [tutorial](http://technoroy.blogspot.com/2008/06/faint-search-for-faces.html) I used to learn about basic Faint face detection. However it did not work for me ad-hoc, I even ended up downloading the whole Faint source and changing it a bit so that I wouldn't get a `NullPointerException`. I found the code included in [this project](http://code.google.com/p/m4noting/source/browse/trunk/src/Faint/?r=5) (I am not quite sure if it is legally included). The code should help you get acquainted with the basic functionalities.

However, when I got everything fixed I did not quite get the expected results: on a single passport pic I got up to 7 faces detected. Maybe it was just me misconfiguring the library... Many people seem to praise this library.

Hope my bit helps you get started with faint.